# Sorting list of strings with numbers and ranges

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

**Input List:** `"3 years", "5 - 7 years", "3 - 6 years","3 - 8 years", "3 - 5 years", "5 years"`
**Expected Output list:** `"3 years","3 - 5 years","3 - 6 years","3 - 8 years","5 years", "5 - 7 years"`

I want to sort the list of String like shown above, I have tried using Collection.sort in Array list but I am not getting the expected output. My output is shown below. String with a hyphen is showing before the string without the hyphen. But its getting sorted.

**My output sorted list:** `"3 - 5 years","3 - 6 years","3 - 8 years","3 years","5 - 7 years","5 years",`

Comment: Write a suitable Comparator.

Comment: You will need to capture the years out of the string and as mentioned use a suitable comparator on top of those

Answer (score 1):

Your list has strings, so the `Collections.sort()` has sorted the list based on string comparison. 
If you want it to sort differently, you have to use a **suitable Comparator**, please try the below code:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("3 years");
list.add("5 - 7 years");
list.add("3 - 6 years");
list.add("3 - 8 years");
list.add("3 - 5 years");
list.add("5 years");

// sort the list
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {

  @Override
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
      // remove all the non - digits from the string
      String n1 = o1.replaceAll("\\D", "");
      String n2 = o2.replaceAll("\\D", "");
      return n1.compareTo(n2);
  }
});

System.out.println(list);
// output is 
// [3 years, 3 - 5 years, 3 - 6 years, 3 - 8 years, 5 years, 5 - 7 years]
```

Comment: Its a concat based sort, will break as soon as you hit double digit or more years eg. adding 3 - 50 years and 30 - 50 years will result in: [3 years, 30 - 50 years, 3 - 5 years, 3 - 50 years, 3 - 6 years, 3 - 8 years, 5 years, 5 - 7 years]

Answer (score 0):

Adding another one to the mix. One can certainly write more readable code but adding a concise one

```
    Pattern rangePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(\\s-\\s(\\d+))?\\syears");
    Function<Map.Entry<String, Optional<List<Optional<String>>>>, Integer> getStartYear = e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getValue().flatMap(value -> value.get(0)).orElse("0"));
    Function<Map.Entry<String, Optional<List<Optional<String>>>>, Integer> getEndYear = e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getValue().flatMap(value -> value.get(1)).orElse("0"));
    Function<MatchResult, List<Optional<String>>> captureRangeYearsAsList = m -> List.of(Optional.ofNullable(m.group(1)), Optional.ofNullable(m.group(3)));

    List.of("3 years", "5 - 7 years", "3 - 6 years", "3 - 8 years", "3 - 5 years", "5 years", "3 - 50 years", "30 - 50 years").stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s -> rangePattern.matcher(s).results()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> Map.entry(e.getKey(), e.getValue().map(captureRangeYearsAsList).findFirst()))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(getStartYear)
                    .thenComparing(getEndYear))
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey()));
```

Output

```
3 years
3 - 5 years
3 - 6 years
3 - 8 years
3 - 50 years
5 years
5 - 7 years
30 - 50 years
```